# How to get current date in sql

Tags: asp.net, sql

I have a table in database and it has a column named 'Modified date'. Whenever i edit some data from the form in asp.net web form i should be able to fill the database table column 'Modified date' with the current date automatically.
Is there any way out for it.I am stuck with it.

Comment: Like where should i try it? I mean where should i declare it.

Comment: Yes. Getdate() is SQl -Server function

Comment: getdate() method when used in **Database** will get current **System date** & **Time** and will add it to the required Field in DateTime Format.

Comment: k but i got to display only date in the web page but not the time. In this case how can i get only date?

Comment: In this case you can format your date field/variable from date time to desired date formats. check my edited answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set

> getdate()

something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ColumnName]
Go
```

as default in your table will give you current insert date and time for Sql server

There are two possible ways :

> 1. From your code behind
> 2. From Select Query from Database

example to select only date from date time :

```
//from code behind
Variable_Name = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

or

```
-- from Database query
SELECT CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it either as Krunal says or hardcode in your insert query in `C#` (or `VB)`:

```
Insert into..... values ( ...., SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 106),...,)
```

this inserts into format: `dd/mmm/yy`

Answer (score 0):

You can use GETDATE() function!

Answer (score 0):

Set default constraint on your DateTime field that will cause the current date/time to be inserted when you insert a new row.

To set the date when updates are made you can use a [Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgYourTableUpdateTimestamp
  ON dbo.YourTable FOR UPDATE
AS BEGIN
   UPDATE 
      dbo.YourTable 
   SET 
      YourTimeStampColumn = GETDATE()
   FROM 
      Inserted Ins
   WHERE
      dbo.YourTable.SomeUniqueId = Ins.SomeUniqueId
END
```

Comment: I am getting output even by this method.But little more complicated i think. Anyways thank you.

Comment: The Trigger executes on any update, the default value just on insert. Thats the difference. That's why i told you both.